# Reading Superscript and Subscript in .doc file using Apache poi?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I have a `.doc` file, I Want to find superscript and subscript using `Apache-poi`.

Answer (score 1):

Following example shows a way to read superscript/subscript from a docx file.  Doc will be similar too.

```
package demo.poi;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.VerticalAlign;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class DocReaderTest {

    @Test

    public void showReadDocWithSubscriptAndSuperScript() throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        File docFile = new File("C:/temp/sample.docx");

        XWPFDocument hdoc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.openOrCreate(docFile));

        Iterator<XWPFParagraph> paragraphsIterator = hdoc.getParagraphsIterator();
        while (paragraphsIterator.hasNext()) {
            XWPFParagraph next = paragraphsIterator.next();
            for (XWPFRun xwrun : next.getRuns()) {
                VerticalAlign subscript = xwrun.getSubscript();
                String smalltext = xwrun.getText(0);
                switch (subscript) {
                    case BASELINE:
                        System.out.println("smalltext, plain = " + smalltext);
                        break;
                    case SUBSCRIPT:
                        System.out.println("smalltext, subscript = " + smalltext);
                        break;
                    case SUPERSCRIPT:
                        System.out.println("smalltext, superscript = " + smalltext);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While i execute your code it shows `The method getRuns undefined for the type XWPFParagraph` error. I put `junit-4.1.jar` and `poi-ooxml-3.5-FINAL.JAR` files, I don't know how to rectify this error? Please help me to solve this error.